# A $2$-dim manifold $M$ is contained in a sphere around the origin if and only if every $\gamma :[0,1] \to M$ satisfies $\int_\gamma xdx+ydy+zdz = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, differential-forms, connectedness

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a $2$-dimensional smooth and connected manifold. I need to prove that the following two claims are equal:

1. For every smooth path $\gamma :[0,1] \to M$ it satisfies $$\int_\gamma xdx + ydy +zdz = 0$$
2. $M$ is contained in a sphere around the origin.

I started by writing $\omega = xdx+ ydy+zdz$. Then the function $f(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2} +c$ satisfies $\omega  = df$, which means that $\omega$ is exact.

Thus, I can write $\int_\gamma \omega  = f(\gamma(1)) - f(\gamma(0))$

From here it is easy to see that $2 \rightarrow 1$ because if we assume $2$, then every point on $M$ is on the same sphere, which means that for every $(x,y,z) \in M$: $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$ for the same $r$ and then $f(\gamma(1)) - f(\gamma(0)) = 0$

However, I don't see how to prove $1 \rightarrow 2$. I think it has to do with the fact that $M$ is connected, since I didn't use it yet, but I don't know how.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $1 \implies 2$, you use the equation $0 = \int_\gamma \omega = f(\gamma(1)) - f(\gamma(0))$ to prove that $f$ is locally constant on $M$, because any two points in a coordinate neighborhood of $M$ are endpoints of some smooth path.

Since $M$ is connected, it follows that $f$ is globally constant.

Hence $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is constant on $M$, so $M$ is contained in a sphere around the origin.

Comment: So it did use connectedness. Thanks!